# Misaligned text strings in pgfplots with view option set

Tags: pgfplots, matlab, matlab2tikz

Please see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229392/make-visible-node-text-outside-of-pgfplot-axes-range) post for more background.

The problem is that tick mark labels explicitly specified by code of the form:

```
text(x(k),y(k),labs{k},'horizontalalignment',horizk,...
'verticalalignment',vertk, ...
'rotation',rotang(k), ...
'fontsize',gfontsize*scl(k), ...
'color',gcolor, ...
'tag','m_grid_xticklabel', ...
'fontname',gfontname);
```

in Matlab (matlab2tikz is run, .tex compiled with pdflatex) are not properly aligned (vertical only, as far as I can tell) when the 'camera view angle' is adjusted with say, `view(45,45)`.

Here are the axis options from the .tex code:

```
\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
unbounded coords=jump,
clip=false,
view={45}{45},
scale only axis,
xmin=-0.000750572061953379,
xmax=0.000750572061953379,
xtick={-0.0005,0,0.0005},
xticklabels={{-1},{-0.5},{0},{0.5},{1}},
ymin=-0.000901759142452274,
ymax=0.000901887945571112,
ytick={-0.0005,0,0.0005},
yticklabels={{-1},{-0.5},{0},{0.5},{1}},
zmin=-1e+16,
zmax=0,
ztick={-1e+16,-9e+15,-8e+15,-7e+15,-6e+15,-5e+15,-4e+15,-3e+15,-2e+15,-1e+15,0},
hide axis,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left,
axis on top,
clip=false
]
```

as well as, the .tex code associated with the label.

```
\node[left, inner sep=0mm, rotate=359.980625982625, text=black]
at (axis cs:-0.000768608531802478,0.000872799628421937,0) { 39'};
```

I have also attached the compiled figure

[image]

Comment: Welcome at tex.sx! What you show here appears to be a defect/weakness in `matlab2tikz`. You should post the same question there. A correct solution would probably make use of `xticklabel cs` and `near xticklabel` anchors (and its friends), compare the `pgfplots` manual section "4.9 Axis Descriptions". If you want to repair the figure at hand and you want help here, I suggest to file a complete minimal example such that we can reproduce the figure.

Comment: Once again, it always seem to work better to do normal tikz graphics AFTER \end{axis}.  You can save \coordinates using (cs axis: x,y) inside the axis environment and use them later.

Comment: You can post bug reports for `matlab2tikz` at https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/issues

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about a bug in matlab2tikz.